# Add the ability to render comments when the comment-list elements should be filled with text "Loading..." and show results one by one

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to render results one by one with some text like "Loading..." and show results one by one. I found answers at [one](https://gist.github.com/aligos/be1c08dee91e3c88873bc04a16a49f8a), [two](https://codepen.io/JenDixon/pen/ayRoEr) and tried to solve this  but it shows only one loading text and renders, shows all results at a time. The results should appear one after the other, with the order preserved. If any error occurs during the loading, the tag should be left empty. How to solve this challenge? For full question please refer [here](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/would-like-add-ability-render-comments-previously-static-website-comments-submitted-via-mo-q68528723)

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Render Comments</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="comment-list" data-count=1></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
"use-strict";

var commentList = $(".comment-list");
var count = $(".comment-list").data("count");
var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=" + count;

$.ajax({
  url: url,
  method: "GET",
  beforeSend: function () {
    commentList.html("Loading...");
  },
  success: function (data) {
    commentList.empty();
    data.forEach(function (comment) {
      commentList.append(`
           <div class="comment-item">
              <div class="comment-item__username">${comment.id}</div>
              <div class="comment-item__message">${comment.name}</div>
          </div>`);
    });
  },
  error: function () {
    // commentList.empty();
    data.forEach(function () {
    commentList.append(`
         <div class="comment-item">
         <div>Oops! Error occured to show the results</div>
         </div>`);
    });
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider doing this with CSS instead of with javascript.  There are many examples including [link](https://dev.to/caroso1222/how-to-create-fancy-revealing-animations-with-these-simple-css-tricks-4gjk).  If you insist on doing this with javascript you need to break up the code adding the elements to the page using setInterval or setTimeout.